# Google apps script get the width and height of a line in Google slides

Tags: google-apps-script, google-slides

I need to get the width and height of the page element on Google slide which is of type LINE.

How do I get the width and height of the line if it is not horizontally parallel. A line can be dialognal or parallel or vertical.

I have tried with

```
    slide.getPageElements.asLine().getWidth()

//.getHeight()
```

Answer (score 0):

The output of `getPageElements()` is an array of PageElement, which you loop through to get the *type*, *width* and *height* of each PageElement.

**For example:**

Here I have 2 lines with different length and width and I used the following methods:

1. `getPageElementType()`: to filter the data to "LINES" only
2. `getHeight()` to get the line height
3. `getWidth()` to get the line width
4. `getRotation()` to get the angle. You can also use this to determine if a line is diagonal, parallel or vertical.

[image]

**Code:**

```
function myFunction() {
  var slide = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation();
  var selected = slide.getSelection();
  var page = selected.getCurrentPage();
  var pageElements = page.getPageElements(); 
  pageElements.forEach(elem => {
    if(elem.getPageElementType() == "LINE"){
      Logger.log("Height: "+elem.getHeight());
      Logger.log("Width: "+elem.getWidth());
      Logger.log("Angle: "+elem.getRotation());
    }
  })
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

### References:

- [getPageElements()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/page#getpageelements)
- [PageElement](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/page-element#getPageElementType())
- [getPageElementType()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/page-element#getpageelementtype)
- [getHeight()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/line#getheight)
- [getWidth()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/line#getwidth)
- [getRotation()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/line#getrotation)